# batch parse all files of drag & dropped directory with and without spaces

Tags: batch-file

I have this somewhat very easy script, that goes takes a dragged and dropped folder and recursively writes in all filenames and opens the file:

```
set File=aTextfile.txt

  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir %1  /s /b') do (
    echo %%a >> "%File%"    
  )

aTextfile.txt
```

Now I noticed some weird behavior.
If I drag from a folder, which in some way has () in its filesname or is a subfolder of one with (), like 
I:(abc)
I:(abc)\def
being the folder dropped, it will cease to work.
replacing %1 with "%1" does the job it make it work again. But weirdly, it won't for some other filenames not.

Let's call the code with just %1 A.bat and with "%1" B.bat.

Some quick testcases got me these behaviors:

I:(abc)

I:(abc)\def

I:(abc)(abc)

I:[abc](abc)

I:[abc]\def

do not work with A, but do with B

I:\abc def

I:(abc)\abc def

I:[abc]\abc def

works with A, but not B

I:\abcdef

I:[abc]\def
works with both

So the behavior seems to have primarily trouble with () and spaces. Is there some elegant way, so that this behavior does not appear?

I first thought of checking against spaces in the dragged root folder string (which looks nasty enough as far I looked as substring checks), and add "" to it before the loop, but since it also happens inside the loop with subfolders, it wouldn't really help.

Comment: Try "%~1" the ~ removes quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with the code below and it worked for file named aa(){}[].txt (on Windows7)
Result file contains

```
> "C:\Temp\ (s)s{s}d[r]\ r[t]y{u}d(e)\ d(){}[].txt"
```

I enclosed in double quotes directory name parameter and echo text.

```
set File=aTextfile.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%~1" /a-d /s /b') do (
    if "%%~xa" NEQ ".txt"  if "%%~xa" NEQ ".dox"  if "%%~xa" NEQ ".bat" (
       >> "%File%" echo "%%a"
    )
)
```

Comment: Yours is exactly, what I did in Version B.bat, which causes other bahavior. jeb's "%~1" solved that, through.

Comment: Give this one another shot.  The `/a-d` switch returns only files, which you seem to be after, and some other tweaks.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's very cool, too! Thanks! 
As to that, is there actually also a way to filter out filetypes? Like list everything except *.txt? (I have seen some examples for the other way round, I think, nut not this way around.)

Comment: Edited response to match your criteria (not .txt files). Also - please remove /a-d switch if you want folder names to be echoed to aTextFile.

Comment: Thanks! Is there actually also a way to set multiple exclusions? (Like all txt, doc, docx) As far as I now, in batch there is no simple "and"/"or" operator, and if statements put into if statements, aren't very beautiful either.

Comment: Edited to add multiple exclusions. There's not or/and operators in batch. However, and operator is easy to workaround by using multiple if statements. Good luck.